# Searching using normal characters not working but it's working with special characters

Tags: python, django, search, admin

I'm working on app in django 1.11 and I have problem with searching in admin panel in django.

When I type in admin panel for example `müller` - it is ok, I have results. But when I try to find for example `muller` - I have no results.

There is some way to solve this issue?

edit:

I model I have setted **str** but I return not this field which I'm trying to find.

Comment: Well `muller` is not the same as `müller`, right? What are you expecting from the search `muller` ?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I know but some users can just type muller and expected some results.

Comment: Then your users have wrong expectations. You can of course cater to that but that's a different question. This question can be answered with "working as intended".

Comment: For English names, you can solve the fuzzy-matching problem by e.g. storing (and searching for) the soundex representation of the name. Maybe there's something similar for German names?

Comment: If you happen to use PostgreSQL as your database I could answer the implicit question of how one could achieve the desired behavior as I have implemented that before. In that case I'd recommend editing the question to explicitly ask for that though.

Comment: This has actually __nothing__ to do with "character encodings" (tag removed), "normal characters" or "special characters" - it's just that "ü" and "u" are not the same character, period.